# No EFI System Partition was found

Tags: uefi

I have followed the steps in the installation menu, but I am not sure which option to choose from in the "Device for boot loader installation" section. My listed options are:

`/dev/sda` ATA WDC WD5000LPVT-0 (500.1 GB)
`/dev/sda1`
`/dev/sda2`

Which option among the three should I choose?

And after choosing `/dev/sda2` I get the following message: NO EFI System partition was found. This system will likely not be able to boot successful, and the installation process may fail. Please go back and add an EFI System Partition, or continue at your own risk.

[image]

Comment: If you're not using a uEFI machine, you can ignore that message as it's only a warning (*however if you are using a uEFI/EFI machine it's real & your machine won't boot*).  I see in your picture you have sda2 for boot loader; you select a device thus it's SDA for bootloader, though the ESP or EFI System Partition will be a partition (sda1/sda2 etc).  You've not provided OS/release details, but I don't see an ESP listed for windows (*unless it's on a different device/drive*).

Comment: You show one NTFS & one ext4 partition. The ESP - efi system partition must be FAT32 with boot,esp flags (if using gparted). Recommended 500 to 600MB, but more for multiple boot or those that may want to try SystemD boot. If one install on smaller drive 50 to 100MB can be enough.

Answer (score 0):

How to Install Ubuntu 20.04.5 with Manual Partitions | UEFI + Manual Partitions |
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFvpdX9kKas

Hope this helps